# How to barplot an object of type 'double' in R?

Tags: r, double, bar-chart

I'm having problems with plotting a variable (named 'mean_impo_sort', see image).

I'm using barplot function as follows: 
barplot(mean_impo_sort, las =2, mar = c(15, 3, 2, 2)), and I have this plot (see image 2)

Can anyone help?

```
NB: typeof(mean_impo_sort) -> "double"
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I'm having problems to add the image of the variable.                 the variable mean_impo_sort:                                                                        
IC1           14.7071638
MW             9.8199385
T.N..O.        9.6950397
T.N..N.        8.6261910
X4A            7.9800090
H5m            7.8998727

Comment: You're question is a bit difficult to understand. You have a variable that is named `mean_impo_sort` (in a DataFrame, I'm assuming). Is the variable discrete or continuous? In order to use the `barplot` function, you have to have the right data type

Comment: my variable is continuous

Comment: Barplots won't generally work well with continuous data

Comment: Ok I see. Thank you for your answer

Comment: I think what you want to create is a histogram

Comment: Yes exactly. How can I do it please?

Comment: Actually not really a histogram. My variable contains descriptors with their respective importance so I want to visualise the most important variables in my data set. I need another function than hist()

Comment: Hmm....so there are two variables then? The first with the data and second with description? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes! the first is my descriptors and the second is their relative importance. You can find how this variable is presented under "enter image description here" in my post

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `cut(..., breaks)` to transform a numeric into discrete bins. You can customize breaks to use whatever function you want (e.g. linear, log, exponential, etc.)